# How to change the WP7 List SelectedItem Background in Dynamic Data template?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list in my application which uses a dynamic item template defined in the app.xaml  and attached to it in the run time in C# code.

The thing is I want to change the background of the selected item, but there is no template available in my page.xaml to edit a copy of the item template for the selected state.

Is there is a way to change the selected item background from the C#. Or even define a state in app.xaml to give it to the list?

Answer (score 0):

There is.  If you have access to Expression Blend, you will be able to modify the default XAML to change how the selected state in VisualStateManager is handled.  It is also possible to find the default XAML that is used and override that in App.Xaml.

Essentially, you need to define a new style resource for the ListBoxItem, and apply that to the listbox.  For example...

```
<ListBox Margin="0" Name="MyListBox" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" />


<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
<!-- This is the bit you are specifically interested in -->
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush"/>
                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
<!-- This is the end of the bit you are specifically interested in -->
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Comment: The problem is that he never changes the back ground image and even the story board don't change the Background , My main target is changing the back ground

Comment: This is just an example of the code you will need to put in, *and edit to suit your needs*

Comment: I tried to change the Background but it didn't work for me , I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or what , Would you please post a sample code of the right way
Note: I did change the opacity when selected , but as for the background it didn't work for me

Comment: '<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
          <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.795" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
           <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FF952727"/>
           </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>'

Comment: Sorry for the mixed up code , i just don't know how to format it right here :$ .
This is the code in the selected visual state , the opacity works fine ,but the back ground don't change

Comment: Thy this article -> http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part1-Control-Template