# Separate VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups to a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there any way to separate the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` into a `ResourceDictionary` ?

Basically I want something like

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups x:Name="MyVisualGroups">
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="A" />
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="B" />
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="C" />
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

but it obviously doesn't work. Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap them in a style objct, you should be able to make this work.  Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274706/change-wp7-list-selected-item-background-in-dynamic-data-template) for an example of how the VSM stuff is wrapped to restyle the selected state in a listbox.

Note : I am not sure if that would work for a set of generic VisualStates, though.  It does work for the whole of a listbox ItemContainerStyle settings, though.